# How to extend sandboxed sinon with custom methods and fields

Tags: javascript, mocking, extend, sinon

Suppose I want extend sinon by adding my own special stub:
I can just write:

```
sinon.specialStub = function() {
    return this.stub().returns('SPECIAL');
};
```

Or I can use sinon.extend and write something like:

```
    sinon.extend(sinon, {
      specialStub: function() {
        return this.stub().returns('SPECIAL');
      }
    });
```

which will do basically the same.

Everything will work just as expected but invoking  this method with `var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();` will fail.

Here's the only known workaround I can think of:

```
 var sandbox =  sinon.extend(sinon.sandbox.create(), {
      specialStub: function() {
        return this.stub().returns('SPECIAL');
      }
 });
```

The quesion is - does any one know how to extend sinon and to see those extended methods in sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is to add the method to `sinon.collection`.

```
sinon.collection.specialStub = function() { return this.stub().returns('Special'); }
var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
console.log(sandbox.specialStub);
```

Might consider asking sinon's maintainer to find out if that's brittle because it taps into things they consider internal to the library.